# How to prove this statement of big o notation?

Tags: math, big-o

How to prove this:

1. 4<sup>n</sup> = O(8<sup>n</sup>)
2. 8<sup>n</sup> = O(4<sup>n</sup>)?

So what are the `C` and `n0` values for both cases?

Comment: I am terribly sorry, I mis-type the question. Can you guys re-answer the question (edited section)? Or should I post as a new question? I am really sorry :(

Comment: @rachel, I've tidied it up as best I could but I'm still not sure I understand the question. Leave a comment on how you want it changed and we'll do our best to fix it. Example: did you mean "O(4^n) = O(8^n)"?

Comment: @paxdiable: Thanks for fixing. But will it cause any confusion as the answers dont match the question? Unless, the sharptooth and JC edit their answer. (I hope they will)

Comment: S**t happens :-) It wouldn't be the first time the final question changes and hopefully (1) sharptooth and JC will be watching and (2) people will take it easy on them if they're not watching (since it's evident the question has changed). We'll leave a notification. Unfortunately, the question may still not make sense. Is it currently correct or do you want more changes?

Comment: @paxdiablo: You are so nice :)

Comment: Wow! With the edits I seriously doubt that the second statement holds true.

Comment: Omg... @sharptooth: what makes you think so? Please... I have been struggling this questions for 2 days. Come on, help me!!!!!!!

Comment: @rachel: there should be some indication about n : most likely (n -> infinity) that's the most usual case but without that the question is incomplete.

Comment: @kriss: Thats the complete question. I am analyzing tanascius answer. I think, I am there. He is really a nice + patient guru

Comment: @rachel: ok, then it's definitely n going to infinity, sometimes it's considered as "implicit". I suggest you replace your initial equations with inequations (as described in wikipedia) and notice you just have positive numbers. All is left is very simple math without any confusing big-O left. But I guess you are nearing that point with the help of tanascius.

Comment: @kriss: I am going to sleep soon. very tired, can you help me on another questions? You can see the links under tanascius answer's comments. its 4 am here ..@_@

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*EDIT:* I tried to clarify I bit more ...

1.
For a proof (see [formal definition of Big-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition)) we have to find any `C` and `n0`, that 4<sup>n</sup> <= C * 8<sup>n</sup> for all n > n0. 
So - to prove your case 1 it is all about finding an example for these two values. We will try ... the equation I just quoted from wikipedia says:

```
f(n) = O(g(n))
```

*if and only if there exists a positive real number C and a real number n0 such that*

```
|f(n)| <= C * |g(n)| for all n > n0
```

where f(n) = 4<sup>n</sup> and g(n)=8<sup>n</sup>

```
4^n    <= C * 8^n
4^n    <= C * 2^n * 4^n
1      <= C * 2^n
```

So we choose `C` to be 1 and `n0` to be 1, too. The equation is true -> case 1 proven.

2.
Since I guess, that this is homework - you should give it a try yourself - I can help you a bit more, as soon as you provide results of your own tries.
Hint: just try to find a `C` and a `n0` there, too - maybe you can prove, that there never exists any pair of `C` and `n0` for the equation ... ^^

Comment: @downvoter: If you down vote, you must have different opinion huh? Can you try answer and let us discuss?

@tanascius: Thanks for the answer for case1. Case 2, i get C 2 but n0 is XX? I dun understand how to get n0...

Comment: (1)4^n <= C * 2^n * 4^n
Thus, 2 is the C

(2) 2^n <= C

Comment: @rachel: I interpret your result as: *Whatever `C` you choose, there will be no `x0`, so that all `2^n` with n > x0 will be smaller than C.*

Comment: So, for case 2, its an invalid statement? How about case 1? C is 2, n0 = 0??

Comment: @rachel: I case 2 there is no solution -> no proof -> statement incorrect. In case one we already found a solution for the equation (C=1, x0=1) -> proof -> statement correct.

Comment: Did you read and understand the formal definition of Big-O? *f(x) = O(g(x)) if and only if there exists a positive real number M and a real number x0 such that ...*

Comment: @rachel: I edited, please tell me whether you understand the proof for case 1, because we don't have to talk about case 2 as long as you don't understand what I wrote ...

Comment: @tan: Ok, lets forget the case2. I understand until this part: 1 <= C * 2^n. But I dunno how to prove, or find the value of C and n0. I think, u  must be feel very pissed off of my stupidity. But trust me, I am really trying very hard to understand.

Comment: @rachel: ok, the trick is that you don't calculate the values ... you just pick them as you like. Here is the equation: *1 <= C * 2^n* - and now I ask you: give values for C and n0 that this equation is true for C and all n >= n0 ... you just choose C to be one ... no reason given. So when is *1 <= 2^n*? Obviously for all n>=0 ... so you can choose any number > 0 for n0 and that's all: *1 <= 1 * 2^0*, *1 <= 1 * 2^1*, *1 <= 1 * 2^1*, *1 <= 1 * 2^2*, ... done

Comment: @tan: For case1, if C = 2, n0 = 1, it returns a true statement as well. So as for C =4,5,6 ..., Thus, can I say, c>=1, n0 = 1?

Comment: It means that you were able to find a C and a n0 for this equation. And that is all that's needed ... *... if and only if there exists a positive real number C and a real number n0 such that ...* By finding two (randomly chosen or somehow selected) values you already provided the proof.

Comment: @rachel: For case 2 you are still looking for a fixed C and a n0 so that the equation *2^n <= C* is valid for **all n >= n0** ... You said C = 2 and n0 = 1 ... let's see, I pick an n >= you n0 which shall be 1000. Is 2^1000 <= 2? No it is not. Try to find another pair - and you won't find any pair - I am sure.

Comment: @tan: Now i get it. because C is a constant, so it will always same no. In this case, you chose 1, so 1 times any number of n0 thats > 0, will make the statement is true. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, it is important to understand that C is a constant, while n0 is only a lower bound ... I will not use n0 for a proof, but all numbers n >= n0 ...

Comment: @rachel: for case 2. Can a function going **downward** get higher than any fixed value greater than the initial one.

Comment: @tan: I think, I finally undestand the concept. I have a big problem now, how should I thank you? I really want to meet and say millions of thank you thank you thank you........

Comment: @rachel ... no problem, I am happy as long as this all lead to anything :)

Comment: @tan: I Love u ^_^. Oh ya, now I understand why you say case2 is invalid statement. I am so happy now :) :) :)

Comment: @rachel: great ... that was my longest comment-based conversation on SO so far :) bye ^^

Comment: @tan: I have another question. But, I really feel that, I should not bug you anymore. Its about how to determine best case and worst case of a function. If you dont mind, can you give me about 5 more minutes? I need hint

Comment: Maybe you want to ask a new question here on SO? You can post the link here as a comment - but don't expect me to answer really early - it is past 7pm and I am going home right now ... I will come back later this evening

Comment: Its 3 am here. I am still studying. Okay, I will post 2 more questions and the links here in comment sections. I will wait for ya. If I sleep, could you please add my yahoo email?

Comment: Q(1):http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669437/how-to-find-the-formula-of-best-case-and-worst-case-of-my-algorithm and Q(2):http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669467/sorting-the-order-of-growth-of-the-functions

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember of the law of logarithms:

log<sub>b</sub>(x<sup>y</sup>) = (y)log<sub>b</sub>(x)

I think this is a good starting point. I'm not going to finish because this is a homework assignment. ;)

**UPDATE:**

The more I look at it, the more I think that something is missing from the original question. Define what *C* and *n<sub>0</sub>* are, for starters.

Comment: Erm.. Still no clue about it. My answer for case 1: C = 2 N0 = dunno. Case 2: c>= 2^n N0 also dunno. Is that correct?

Comment: I already tried my best, please help me? I want to study, thats why I ask this question. If I dont care about my school, I wont be asking here and probably shopping with my friends. Please, help me :(

Comment: @rachel7660: It's been a while since I've done Big-O proofs ;) Would you mind giving a clear definition of C and n0 in the question?

Comment: @rachel7660: C has to be a constant, so you can't choose C >= 2^n.  If you can prove that C needs to be at least 2^n (i.e., not constant), then you have demonstrated a contradiction which means that statement 2 is false.

Comment: @Frustrated: For C and n0 see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition (where C is called M  and n0 is x0)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: C is the constant. n0 is the minimal value of the function, so that it will perform worst case. Well, I am not good at memorizing terms.

Comment: @tanascius: Thanks. You are really a big help.