# Sorting the order of growth of the functions?

Tags: math, exponential

Please order the function belows by growth rate from fastest to slowest:

- n^10
- 2^n
- nlog(n)
- 10^6

And my answer is:

- 2^n
- n^10
- nlog(n)
- 10^6

Is my answer correct?

Comment: See what order they come out to be when n = 1000.

Comment: @tanascius: ordered by fastest *growth* to slowest, not fastest *running time*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems about right. As way of education, consider what happens when you feed in different `n` values (using rough powers of 10 rather than exact values):

```
 n      2^n       n^10    n log n   10^6
 ----   -------   -----   -------   ----
    1   10^0.3    10^0    10^0      10^6
   10   10^3      10^10   10^1      10^6
  100   10^30     10^20   10^2      10^6
 1000   10^301    10^30   10^3      10^6
10000   10^3010   10^40   10^4      10^6
```

So, in terms of how fast they grow, you're list is correct.

- `10`<sup>`6`</sup> doesn't grow at all.
- `n log n` increases its power-of-ten by one for each step.
- `n`<sup>`10`</sup> increases its power-of-ten by 10 for each step.
- `2`<sup>`n`</sup> *multiplies* its power-of-ten by ten each step.